# Convergence of exponentially-distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Hi I'm kind of a newbie of probability and I would like some help/hint with the following exercise:

Let $(Y_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of Exponential random variables. Let moreover $\mathbb{E}Y_n = \lambda$

1. Prove or disprove the following statement:

$$ \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{Y_{n}}{\lambda\log n}=1\quad \text{ a.s.}$$

2. Define now $Z_n=\max\{X_1,...,X_n\} \ \forall n$, prove or disprove that:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{Z_{n}}{\lambda\log n}=1\quad \text{ a.s.}$$

I kind of have the feeling that i should apply in some way the Borel-Cantelli lemma but I'm really confused. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You wish to prove that $P(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} = 1) =1$. It suffices to prove that $$P(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} > 1) = P(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} < 1)=0$$

---

Let $\displaystyle X_n = \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}$.

Note that $\displaystyle \limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} > 1 = \{w\in \Omega, \limsup_n \frac{Y_n(w)}{\lambda \log n} > 1\}  = \bigcup_N \bigcap_n \bigcup_{k\geq n}\left(X_k> 1+\frac 1N \right)$.

It suffices to prove that $\forall N, P\left(\bigcap_n \bigcup_{k\geq n}\left(X_k> 1+\frac 1N \right) \right)=0$.

But $P\left(\bigcap_n \bigcup_{k\geq n}\left(X_k> 1+\frac 1N \right) \right)=P\left(\limsup_n \left( X_n> 1+\frac 1N\right) \right)$.

By Borel-Cantelli, it suffices to prove that $\sum_n P\left( X_n> 1+\frac 1N\right)$ converges. Note that $$P\left( X_n> 1+\frac 1N\right) = P\left(Y_n > \lambda \left( 1 + \frac 1N \right)\log n\right)=\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac 1N}}$$ and convergence follows.

This proves $P(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} > 1) =0$.

---

Note that $$ \begin{aligned}[t] \left(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} \right)< 1 &= \{w\in \Omega, \limsup_n \frac{Y_n(w)}{\lambda \log n} < 1\}  \\&\subset \bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\geq n}\left(\frac{Y_k}{\lambda \log k} < 1\right)\\ &= \liminf_n \left( \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} < 1\right) \end{aligned}$$

Since $\liminf_n \left( \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}<1 \right)=\left(\limsup_n \left(\frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}>1\right) \right)^c $, it suffices to prove that $$P\left( \limsup_n \left( \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}>1\right)\right)= 1$$

As expected we make use of the second Borel Cantelli lemma (**after an independence assumption is added** on the $Y_k$) : $$P\left( \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}>1\right) =P\left( Y_n>\lambda \log n\right)= \frac 1n $$ and the sum diverges, proving the claim.

---

For the second part of your question, I suppose you can proceed similarly.

Comment: Sorry but I have some doubts on the resolution: shouldn't in the first part $\{ \omega \in \Omega : \limsup_n   \frac{X_n(\omega)}{\lambda \log n}>1 \} $ be equal to $\bigcup_N \bigcap_n \bigcup_{k \geq n} ( X_k > 1+ \frac{1}{N} )?$ Moreover how can we prove in the second part that $P(\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\lambda \log n}>1)=1$ when in the first part we showed that it's equal to 0?

Comment: @Random-newbie why are you writing $\frac{X_n(\omega)}{\lambda \log n}$ ? You want to prove that $P(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} = 1) =1$. For notational ease, I have defined $X_n = \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}$.

Comment: Yeah sorry $\frac{Y_n(\omega)}{\lambda \log n}$ my mistake, but still i tink that there is something wrong with that set...a limsup should "get smaller" over time, instead it seems to me that that one is getting bigger as $n$ grows

Comment: @Random-newbie you're right, sorry for the typo

Comment: no problem you are really helping me! Sorry to bother you more but the second part is still unclear to me: in the first step of the proof we showed that  $P(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}>1)=0$ how can we now show in the second part that $P(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}>1)=1$? It would be a contraddiction

Comment: @Random-newbie yet again, I messed up with the notations. I've added parentheses to make it clear that I'm considering $\limsup$ of sets (as opposed to $\limsup$ of real numbers). To sum it up, we have $$\left(\limsup_n \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}\right) < 1 = \{w\in \Omega, \limsup_n \frac{Y_n(w)}{\lambda \log n} < 1\}=\liminf_n \left( \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n} < 1\right)$$ So it suffices to prove that $$P\left( \limsup_n \left( \frac{Y_n}{\lambda \log n}>1\right)\right)= 1$$ This last $\limsup$ is a $\limsup$ of a sequence of **sets**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68203/discussion-between-random-newbie-and-gabriel-romon).

Comment: This might be super obvious, but could you tell me why $\{w\in \Omega, \limsup_n X_k(\omega) > 1\}  = \bigcup_N \bigcap_n \bigcup_{k\geq n}\left(X_k> 1+\frac 1N \right)$?

Comment: @StefanPerko Take $w$ such that $\limsup_n X_n(\omega) > 1$. Then $\sup_{k\geq n}X_k(w)$ is a decreasing sequence (indexed by $n$) that converges to some $a>1$. Consider any $N$ such that $1+\frac 1N < a$. Then $\sup_{k\geq 0}X_k(w) \geq a > 1+\frac 1N $. But there is a subsequence of the $X_k(w)$ that converges to $\sup_{k\geq 0}X_k(w)$, so that $X_n(w)>1+\frac 1N$ infinitely often. // Continued

Comment: Continued // For the other inclusion, consider $w$ and some $N$ such that $\forall n, \exists k\geq n , X_k(w)>1+\frac 1N$. Then for any $n$, $\sup_{k\geq n} X_k(w)>1+\frac 1N$, hence $\lim_n\sup_{k\geq n} X_k(w)\geq 1+\frac 1N >1$.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't get the last sentence of the first part (my knowledge of analysis is severely lacking).

Comment: @StefanPerko my argument for the first part is convoluted, here's a more direct one. Remember that $\sup_{k\geq n}X_k(w)$ decreases to the limit $a$. Since $\sup_{k\geq 0}X_k(w) \geq a$, there exists $k_1$ such that $X_{k_1}(w)\geq a $. But we also have $\sup_{k\geq k_1+1}X_k(w) \geq a$, so there is some $k_2>k_1$ such that $X_{k_2}(w)\geq a$. Repeating the process (you can make it more formal via induction if you wish), $X_n(w)>1+\frac 1N$ infinitely often.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Doesn't $\sup_{k\geq 0} X_k(\omega) \geq a$ merely imply there exists $k_1$ such that $X_{k_1}(w)\geq a$ *or* $\sup_{k\geq 0} X_k(\omega) = a$?

Comment: @StefanPerko Indeed. Let me correct: $\sup_{k\geq 0} X_k(w)>1+\frac 1N$ implies there exists $k_1$ such that $X_{k_1}(w)>1+\frac 1N$. To prove this, consider some $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon < [\sup_{k\geq 0} X_k(w)] - (1+\frac 1{N})$. $[\sup_{k\geq 0} X_k(w)] - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound (by definition of supremum), so there is some $k_1$ such that $[\sup_{k\geq 0} X_k(w)] - \epsilon<X_{k_1}(w)$. By the nature of $\epsilon$, $X_{k_1}(w)>1+\frac 1N$. You can keep going since $\sup_{k\geq k_1+1} X_k(w)\geq a >1+\frac 1N$

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now.